# Cenario VR iOS course is starting from the beginning again and again

Tags: objective-c, virtual-reality

We create a course using cenario VR for mobile. Created course will be run on our ilms on desktop it works fine but on iOS Mobile it will restart after some time.

We Use rustici engine and iEngine to play our course for LMS. Our other course are running fine. We use the same infra for our VR course which will running fine in android side, but in ios after some time it will restart again.

We get following error while debugging the app.

> Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)
>
> CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush].
>
> TIC TCP Conn Failed [16:0x28335de00]: 1:50 Err(50)
>
> Task <7D491FF3-8ADB-4107-9287-68901A2661CB>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50])
>
> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009